# Bash or-equals ||= like Ruby

Tags: bash, command-prompt, pwd, string-substitution

Does Bash have something like ||= ?

I.e., is there a better way to do the following:

```
if [ -z $PWD ]; then PWD=`pwd`; fi
```

I'm asking because I get this error:

```
$ echo ${`pwd`/$HOME/'~'}
-bash: ${`pwd`/$HOME/'~'}: bad substitution
```

So, my plan is to do:

```
if [ -z $PWD ]; then PWD=`pwd`; fi
echo ${PWD/$HOME/'~'}
```

My real question is: "Is there a better way to do the following?"

```
# ~/.bash_profile

# Set prompt to RVM gemset, abbr. of current directory & (git branch).
PROMPT_COMMAND='CUR_DIR=`pwd|sed -e "s!$HOME!~!"|sed -E "s!([^/])[^/]+/!\1/!g"`'
PS1='$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt g) [$CUR_DIR$(__git_ps1)]\$ '
```

Comment: not different (or better) but shorter: `[ -z $PWD ] && PWD=\`pwd\` `

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bash allows for default values:

```
a=${b-`pwd`}
```

If `$b` is undefined, then `pwd` is used instead in assigning `$a`.

Comment: More often, I see another form: `${PWD:-\`pwd\`}` I wonder if they are equivalent

Comment: @GregT if `b` is unset, they will behave the same. If `b` is set to an empty string, however, then `${b-\`pwd\`}` will result in an empty string, but `${b:-\`pwd\`}` will result in the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your prompt to be the working directory with this:

```
PS1='\w '   # Using \W will provide just basename
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (which is more akin to Ruby's or-equals in my opinion) would be:

```
[ -n $PWD ] || PWD=`pwd`
```

Comment: While I like the style, if MyVar is set to a zero length string it will not be set to 'value' in this example, whereas using bash "default values" a la @Manny D, above,  would work arguably correctly, as in: `MyVar=${MyVar-'value'}